# Pump Head Requirement in dividing flow

Tags: mechanical-engineering, pressure

I'll preface this by saying that I'm looking for kind of a simple answer, and will be providing almost all the initial conditions that I'm aware of.

I have a single pump, which is to provide  80 m³/h. The pump connects to a stainless steel pipe manifold (inlet on one cross-sectional end, and 12 outlets on the other cross-sectional end). The outlets are for smaller PVC pipes, which then run up to fountain nozzles. I have valves on the outlets of the manifold to adjust proper flowrate division (each pipe allowing 6.66 m³/h). The pump is located 2m below the fountain nozzles.

Now the real problem is that the nozzles are located at variable lengths. The PVC pipes run up to 55m to the final nozzle, and as short as 15m to the closest nozzle. Each pipe has 4 90° bends. The catalog for the nozzle states a pressure requirement of 0.52 bar for each nozzle to achieve the desired flow (6.66 m³/h)

The question is, what would the total pump head required be?

Would it be:

(Elevation + Pressure Loss in the manifold + **Pressure loss due to friction in the furthest pipe** + Pressure required by the nozzle + **Pressure loss in 4 90 Bends**)

*OR*

(Elevation + Pressure Loss in the manifold + **Sum of Pressure losses due to friction in the all 12 pipes** + Pressure required by the nozzle + **Pressure loss in (4x12) 90 Bends**)

Comment: calculate the pressure drop at each section after each nozzle is passed as the flow rate drops by the amount feeding that nozzle.